# ITfoxtec Identity.Saml2.MvcCore -- SAML ERROR Form key length limit 2048 exceeded

Tags: saml-2.0, asp.net-core-3.1, itfoxtec-identity-saml2

I am using ITfoxtec Identity.Saml2.MvcCore for .net core v3.1 for Single sign on using Ping Identity.

**SAML ERROR Form key length limit 2048 exceeded.**   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.WebUtilities.FormPipeReader.ThrowKeyTooLargeException()
at Microsoft.AspNetCore.WebUtilities.FormPipeReader.ParseValuesSlow(ReadOnlySequence`1& buffer, KeyValueAccumulator& accumulator, Boolean isFinalBlock) at Microsoft.AspNetCore.WebUtilities.FormPipeReader.ParseFormValues(ReadOnlySequence`1& buffer, KeyValueAccumulator& accumulator, Boolean isFinalBlock)
at Microsoft.AspNetCore.WebUtilities.FormPipeReader.ReadFormAsync(CancellationToken cancellationToken)
at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Http.Features.FormFeature.InnerReadFormAsync(CancellationToken cancellationToken)
at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Http.Features.FormFeature.ReadForm()
at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Http.DefaultHttpRequest.get_Form()
at ITfoxtec.Identity.Saml2.MvcCore.HttpRequestExtensions.ToGenericHttpRequest(HttpRequest request)
at Nbc.Score.Remotes.Web.Controllers.HomeController.AssertionConsumerService()

**Failed method**   ITfoxtec.Identity.Saml2.MvcCore.HttpRequestExtensions.ToGenericHttpRequest

Answer (score 0):

It looks like an form property is to lang, more then 2048 characters. It do not look like it is a value length which is a problem but instead a property length.

How dos the raw response look like?